# PHP BINDVALUE NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

tengo el siguiente problema:
No me realiza correctamente el NOT IN del where, probe cambiar las comillas varias veces, utilizar las \ , intenté tambien (:permisosID) pero no hay caso. Sin bindear el :permisosID y poniendo NOT IN $permisosFiltro funciona.. pero no es lo ideal. Algo estoy haciendo mal y no puedo verlo.

El error es claro..
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''(12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)' AND P.ID_ESTADO <> 3\r\n ORDER BY 1 DESC'

```
$permisosFiltro = 1,2,3,4,5,6;


$query = "SELECT
                P.ID_PERMISO,
                P.NOMBRE,
                P.DESCRIPCION,
                P.ID_ESTADO
        FROM ".$this->_schema.".PERMISOS P
            WHERE P.ID_PERMISO NOT IN :permisosID AND P.ID_ESTADO <> 3
        ORDER BY 1 DESC";

        $result = $this->_db->prepare($query);

        $result->bindValue(":permisosID", "(" . $permisosFiltro . ")");
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

De entrada, la primera línea de tu código está mal, no puedes separar valores por coma, debes encerrar todo entre comillas para que sea una cadena o entre corchetes para un arreglo:

```
// Cadena, no es lo adecuado
$permisosFiltro = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
// Arreglo, mucho mejor opción
$permisosFiltro = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Luego, la sintaxis correcta para IN o NOT IN debe ser:

```
columna NOT IN (valor1, valor2, ... valorX)
```

Estás encerrando todo entre comillas y es por eso que te da error. En todo caso, te sugiero usar marcas de remplazo `?` y enviar el arreglo al ejecutar la consulta:

```
$permisosFiltro = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
// Crear arreglo de marcas con la misma cantidad de elementos que el filtro
$marcasArray = array_fill(0, count($permisosFiltro) - 1, '?');
// Crear cadena ?, ?, ... ?
$marcasStr = implode(', ', $marcasArray);
// Crear cadena de consulta
$query = "SELECT
            P.ID_PERMISO,
            P.NOMBRE,
            P.DESCRIPCION,
            P.ID_ESTADO
    FROM {$this->_schema}.PERMISOS P
        WHERE P.ID_PERMISO NOT IN ({$marcasStr}) AND P.ID_ESTADO <> 3
    ORDER BY 1 DESC";

    $result = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    // No es necesario enlazar valores, solo ejecutar y enviar el arreglo
    $result->execute($permisosFiltro);
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

- [array_fill()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-fill.php)
- [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1015) con parámetros de sustitución